# How to convert payload into a json array in mule

Tags: json, mule

I have this payload:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,
```

I want to convert it into a json array so the output should look like this:

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

When I try using the `<json:object-to-json-transformer />` I get this:`"aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,"`, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your payload is a comma separated string, then first transform that to a List then using the `object-to-json-transformer` like so:

```
    <set-payload value="#[Arrays.asList(payload.split(','))]" />

    <json:object-to-json-transformer />
```